# Multiple sound in Media Player application crashed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer, multiplayer

- I have developed app in which there are 4 sound files playing together
- First sound :

  - **on next button press**
    -Second sound :
  - **on previous button press**
- Third sound :

  - **plays sound of item**
- Fourth sound :

  - **plays on item (How item speaks)**
- Everything works well until user play back and fourth quickly, text-to-speech engine crash with

**MediaPlayer: error (-19, 0) android**

- i tried to reset media player , release and stop in next and previous button, but still sound of items stops after few back and fourth.

What i have done :

```
public class A extends Activity {


    int imgArr[] = {R.drawable.a, R.drawable.b, R.drawable.c, R.drawable.d};
    int soundsrc[] = {R.raw.a, R.raw.b, R.raw.c, R.raw.d};
    String pro[] = new String[]{"a", "b", "c", "d"};
    ImageView iView;
    int count = 0;

    TextToSpeech txtToSpeech1;
    MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_names);
        stopService(new Intent(this, PlayMusic.class));


        iView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
        iView.setImageResource(R.drawable.befora);
        txtToSpeech1 = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {


            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                    txtToSpeech1.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
                    txtToSpeech1.speak(pro[count], TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                }
            }
        });

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                aSounds();
            }
        }, 1000);




    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Don't forget to shutdown!
        if (txtToSpeech1 != null) {
            txtToSpeech1.stop();
            txtToSpeech1.shutdown();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void onPause(){
        if(txtToSpeech1 !=null){
            txtToSpeech1.stop();
            txtToSpeech1.shutdown();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    public void aSounds() {
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(ANames.this, soundsrc[count]);
        mp.start();
    }


    public void forwardd(View v) {
        buttonSounds(R.raw.multimedia_button_click);
        if (count < imgArr.length && count >= 0) {
            count++;
            if (count == imgArr.length)
                count = 0;
            iView.setImageResource(imgArr[count]);

            if (txtToSpeech1.isSpeaking()) {
                Log.i("Tag", "Stop speaking");
                txtToSpeech1.stop();
            }

            txtToSpeech1.speak(pro[count], TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            // Execute some code after 2 seconds have passed

            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    aSounds();
                }
            }, 1000);


        }
    }

    public void backwardd(View v) {
        buttonSounds(R.raw.multimedia_button_click);

        if (count >= 0 && count < imgArr.length) {
            count--;
            if (count == -1) {
                count = imgArr.length - 1;
            }
            iView.setImageResource(imgArr[count]);
            txtToSpeech1.speak(pro[count], TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    aSounds();
                }
            }, 1000);


        }
    }

    public void onImageClick(View v) {
        txtToSpeech1.speak(pro[count], TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                aSounds();
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

    public void home(View v) {
        buttonSounds(R.raw.multimedia_button_click);
        Intent ii = new Intent(ANames.this, PlayMusic.class);
        finish();
        startService(ii);
    }

    public void buttonSounds(int src) {
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(ANames.this, R.raw.multimedia_button_click);
        mp.start();
    }


}
```

-- i have been trying since very very very long

-- **tried almost all stack-overflow answers also Google** regarding media player working .

-- **also how to stop , release , reset, start media player on button click, but nothing works for me**..

-- So at last decided to put question in stack-overflow for help

-- any help is heartly welcome and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If the buttons plays a sound effect like 1-4 seconds. Consider using [SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) class. It should be used for that stuff as I know. Media player errors [LINK](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/master/include/media/stagefright/MediaErrors.h) and [LINK](https://github.com/android/platform_external_opencore/blob/master/pvmi/pvmf/include/pvmf_return_codes.h). It seems whoever were getting error 19 needed to release the resource which he was playing.